# Twitter Stream API - 401 Unauthorized

Tags: php, twitter, websocket, stream

I can't open a connection with Twitter Stream API. The only response I can get, no matter what I try, is `401 Unauthorized`.

I've made all kinds of tests, even using some libraries I've found on GitHub.

Even outside my code, using cURL, I can't make it work.

```
$oauth = array( 
    'oauth_consumer_key' => $this->m_oauth_consumer_key,
    'oauth_nonce' => time(),
    'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
    'oauth_token' => $this->m_oauth_token,
    'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
    'oauth_version' => '1.0'
);

$base_info = $this->buildBaseString($this->url, 'GET', $oauth);
$composite_key = rawurlencode($this->m_oauth_consumer_secret) . '&' . rawurlencode($this->m_oauth_token_secret);
$oauth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_info, $composite_key, true));
$oauth['oauth_signature'] = $oauth_signature;
$header = $this->buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth);
```

This is my code for building HTTP Request Header and Signature. I've tried in a lot of different ways, no success.

Anoyone have any ideia that could help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: wish I could help. For now I can only say join the club :( we need some more code I think. It is unclear to me, for instance, what url are you calling. Try with 1.1 to reflect the new api if it's not so, and I am afraid I can't help more because it doesn't work for me either

Answer (score 6):

If you're on Linux, sync your time with an NTP server:

```
$ sudo ntpdate ntp.org
```

Comment: this answer helped me, i guess it should be accepted.[this link](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/connecting) will explain further reasons for 401, in my case it was timestamp, which was just 5 minutes different from my local network time. After updating it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to access the API today with node.js and had the same error. My Windows didn't yet update my clock, so my local computer time was off by an hour(daylight saving time switch was today).
When I changed it, it started to work again.
They should really have some better error message than just plain 401.

Comment: whoa, same thing literally happened to me on android. lol. more detailed error messages would help. theyre using a streaming api so obviously they dont care.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Go to your App Settings screen and change Callback URL to something like yoursite.com. I'm not sure why but once you change that you won't see 401 error anymore.