# Twitter API streaming request returning 401

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I am using [Twitter for Node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter) to make requests to the Twitter API, but I keep getting 401 Error which according to [Twitter Docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/response-codes) means that there was an issue authenticating the request.

I am using the example from the [twitter npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter):

```
const Twitter = require('twitter');

function twitter() {
    var TwitterClient = new Twitter({
        consumer_key: 'MY_KEY',
        consumer_secret: 'MY_SECRET',
        bearer_token: 'MY_TOKEN'

    });

    try {
        TwitterClient.stream('statuses/filter', {
            track: 'javascript'
            }, function(stream) {
                   stream.on('data', function(event) {
                       console.log(event && event.text);
                   });

                   stream.on('error', function(error) {
                       try {
                           throw error;
                       }
                       catch (err) {
                           console.log(err);
                       }
                   });
         });
    } catch(e) {}
}
```

I get the following error in console:

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()**

Doing the GET request from the twitter npm page works fine:

```
    var params = {screen_name: 'nodejs'};
    TwitterClient.get('statuses/user_timeline', params, function(error, tweets, response) {
        if (!error) {
          console.log(tweets);
        }
    });
```

What I've tried:

- Regenerated new tokens and double-checked them
- [Checked for updated system hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594173/twitter-stream-api-401-unauthorized)
- Added access tokens and access secret to authentication

Thank you for your help

Comment: How does the exact err message looks like. Are you setting the proper permission on the Twitter side for you api key?

Comment: I do not think the legacy streaming API works with app only (bearer token) Auth, have you tried with user Auth?

Comment: @AvivLo I get two messages in console: First one is **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()** Second one is `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Status Code: 401
    at Request.<anonymous> (index.js:47181)
    at emitOne (index.js:66253)
    at Request.emit (index.js:66331)
    at Request.onRequestResponse (index.js:34858)
    at emitOne (index.js:66253)
    at module.exports.emit (index.js:66331)
    at module.exports.ClientRequest._connect (index.js:80964)
    at index.js:80855` I have activated Filtered and Sampled Streams: https://imgur.com/rLGcQI6

Comment: @AndyPiper I've tried authenticating access token and access token secret but still same issue.

Comment: Can we do a .catch to catch the error

Comment: I've a project that used the twitter streaming api as well. It's in production now. Check it out. It might helphttps://github.com/Moodli/codevscovid19_moodli_backend

Comment: Thank you @AvivLo I will look into your project for guidance on how to do this correctly, right now I'm trying to figure out how to do a try catch block, I am new to programming and learning things as I go, I'll comment here again once I figure it out!

Comment: No problem. But it says in the error message that there is a uncaught promise, so you can just probably add a catch block some where and catch that error. After that we'll be able to know what's wrong exactly.

Comment: I think I got it @AvivLo I am no longer getting the uncaught promise message but I also didn't get much information about what's wrong, console just shows `Error: Status Code: 401
    at Request.<anonymous> (index.js:47181)
    at (...)` I'm not sure if my try catch block is okay though, I've gone ahead and edited my question with the updated code including the try catch

Comment: Ok. No problem.